# type mismatch error in sql in connecting to mysql from excel vba

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

```
Sub connectmysqlnormal()
Dim objListObj As ListObject

For Each objListObj In ActiveSheet.ListObjects

objListObj.Delete
Next

 ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
 Selection.ClearContents
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "ODBC;DSN=localtest;", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT cpu_avg_statistics_0.LOGDATE as 'Date of Month', cpu_avg_statistics_0.CPU as 'CPU Utilization %' FROM test.cpu_avg_statistics cpu_avg_statistics_0 WHERE (cpu_avg_statistics_0.LOGDATE between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-05') AND  (cpu_avg_statistics_0.SERVER_NAME='adm1') ORDER BY cpu_avg_statistics_0.LOGDATE" _
    )
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_localtest"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

I can connect run the sql in mysql. But when i place in vba code as above,
I got the type mismatch error in the sql statement , please help and tell me what's  wrong?

Comment: Can you run it directly from MySQL?

Comment: yes , i can get the result set after running it in mysql

Answer (score 2):

Try without using Array in the line for:

```
.CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT ..." _
    )
```

Comment: It's the same , type mismatch

Comment: Because CommandText is a primitive type of type "string". An array is an object but it is not of type "string".

Comment: Another Question, I want to name the query to a variable plus a string, say rpt_name=Server_Name & "cpu", .ListObject.DisplayName = rpt_name. i got a run-time 1004 error , application define or object define error , how can I achieve?

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Hi Emmad, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866174/excel-vba-using-variable-as-the-name-of-listobjects      thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following line along with the other QueryTable properies:

```
.CommandType = xlCmdSql
```